# How to return a new dictionary obtained by updating a 2 level dictionary?

Tags: python-3.x

I need to write a function that returns a dictionary obtained by updating a two-level dictionary(dict2). The resulting dictionary (newdict2) contains newdict2[key1][key2] == value. I'm not sure if I have my for loops and if statement set up correctly or how to update the value that needs to be returned.

I have been trying some nested for loops and if statements to no avail. When I try to plug in the testing examples I get a name error. I'll post below. Even though, I'm still not sure my code will work. I receive a nametype error when running test case saying DD is not defined.

my function:

```
def update_dict2(dict2, key1, key2, value):
    newdict2 = {}
    for key1 in dict2:
        for key2 in key1:
            if key1[0] == key2[0]:
                newdict2[key1][key2] == value



x = update_dict2(DD,'aaa','ccc',12)
print(x)


DD = {'aaa' : {'bbb': 'string1','ccc': 'string2', 'ddd' : 'string3' },
 'bbb' : {'ccc':'string4','ddd':'string5','eee':'string6','fff':'string7'},
 'ccc' : {'aaa':'string8','bbb':'string9'}}



Expected results:

1. update_dict2(DD,'aaa','ccc',12)
return value:
 {'aaa': { 'bbb' : 'string1', 'ccc' : 12, 'ddd' : 'string3' },
  'bbb': {'ccc':'string4','ddd':'string5','eee':'string6','fff':'string7'},
  'ccc': { 'aaa' : 'string8', 'bbb' : 'string9' }}

2. update_dict2(DD,'aaa','ggg','string17')
return value:
{'aaa':{'bbb':'string1','ccc':12,'ddd':'string3','ggg':'string17'},
 'bbb':{'ccc':'string4','ddd':'string5','eee':'string6','fff':'string7'},
 'ccc':{'aaa':'string8','bbb':'string9'}
}

3. update_dict2(DD,'ggg','aaa','string17'):

    enter code here

return value:
{'aaa':{'bbb':'string1','ccc':12,'ddd':'string3'},
 'bbb':{'ccc':'string4','ddd':'string5','eee':'string6','fff':'string7'},
 'ccc':{'aaa':'string8','bbb':'string9'},
 'ggg':{'aaa':'string17'}}



Errors:

Error received when running a test case


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/JHA4t.png
```

Answer (score 0):

```
'''This works'''

def update_dict2(dict2, key1, key2, value):
    '''
    This function takes a two-level dicitonary and updates the values at key2 if
    key1 exists. If key1 does not exist, the function adds it to the dictionary with
    it's coinciding key2 and value.
    '''
    if key1 not in dict2:
       dict2[key1] = {key2:value}
    else:
        dict2[key1][key2] = value
    return dict2
```